# How to return a method when some threads in it have finished?

Tags: java, multithreading

I create a ConcurrentHashMap, execute several sql queries at the same time and put the results into the map. Previously I used an AtomicInteger to calculate the number of finished task. One suggests me using Map.size() can be conciser.
For example:

```
    final Map<String, Object> res = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            res.put("first", 1);    // imagine this is the query result
        }
    }).run();
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            res.put("second", 2);   // imagine this is the query result
        }
    }).run();
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            res.put("third", 3);    // imagine this is the query result
        }
    }).run();
    while (true) {
        if (res.size() == 3) {
            break;
        }
    }
    return res;
```

Now the occupancy of CPU is high while the loop spins. Is there anyway better to return after the tasks finished?

Comment: That is not an exception. It's a thread dump. It's just showing you what that thread is doing. Where did you see this?

Comment: replace `.run()` with `.start()` otherwise no threads are getting created, your code is running sequentially

Comment: @Savior I see it from jstack. Sorry I'll correct my post immediately.

Comment: Instead of a busy loop, use something like a `CountDownLatch`.

Comment: Use [CompletableFuture](https://www.baeldung.com/java-completablefuture)

Comment: `.join()` the individual threads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use CountDownLatch:

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;
import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;

public class TestJava {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        final CountDownLatch cdl = new CountDownLatch(3);
        final Map<String, Object> res = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                res.put("first", 1);    // imagine this is the query result
                cdl.countDown();
            }
        }).start();
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                res.put("second", 2);   // imagine this is the query result
                cdl.countDown();
            }
        }).start();
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                res.put("third", 3);    // imagine this is the query result
                cdl.countDown();
            }
        }).start();

        cdl.await();

        System.out.println("res size = " + res.size());

    }
}
```

Comment: I followed your advice and rebuilt the project on server. It took about 500% of CPU before(800% in total). Now it takes about 100%.

Comment: Take care that you must make sure every thread calls `cdl.countDown();` (you can put it in `finally` block).  Or your main thread blocks forever.

Comment: Do you mean the staff in each thread should be surrounded by try...catch...finally and I'd better put cdl.countDown() in each finally block? @shawn

Comment: Yes. Or, if an exception occurs in the worker thread, the `CountDownLatch` will never go to zero.